# Facebook login button - can't redirect page to my veryfity URL

Tags: facebook, button, authentication

I would like to redirect page to my veryfity facebook login url after click to fb login button. Now, when I click to button my page is only refresh and I'm still logout ;/

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js">
</script>
<script>
FB.init({
      appId: '******615845***', cookie: true,
      status: true, xfbml: true
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
window.location = "http://my-page.pl/login.php?mode=fb_login";
});
</script>
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook!</fb:login-button>
```

Where is problem? Why I'm still logout when I clicked to button ?